# setting session value in dropdown in php

Tags: php, session

I am new to php i have set a value in a session variable in 1 page , Now i have to display that session variable value on another page's dropdown as selected, Tried everything but couldn't get it, May be because of bad coding :) , Any help from anyone would be really appreciated. Thanks.

here is my code

Select

```
if($numrows){
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
if($obj->status == 1){
if($subjectId == $obj->id){ 
echo '<option  value="'.obj->id.'" style="color:#000" selected >'.$obj->subject_name.'</option>';
}
else{
echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'" style="color:#000">'.($obj->subject_name).'</option>';   
}
}
}   
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: where `$selected`  defined?

Comment: write `<?php session_start();?>`on top of this code page. and also where `$selected` defined?

Comment: in the question i have updated my original code , session is already been started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the session variable first.

```
<?php
session_start();
$subjectId = ! empty($_SESSION['YOUR_SESSION_VARIABLE']) ? $_SESSION['YOUR_SESSION_VARIABLE'] : '';
?>

<select name="subject_id" class="select-form subjectSelect sub" onchange="ajaxDrp(this.value)" style="background-color: #fff !important; width:159px!important;">
    <option value="" style="color:#000">Select</option>
    <?php
    $sql = "select * from mock_subject ";
    $res = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
    $numrows =mysqli_num_rows($res);
    echo mysql_error();
    if($numrows){
      while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
        if($obj->status == 1){
          $selected = ($subjectId == $obj->id) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
          echo '<option  value="'.$selected.'" style="color:#000" $selected>'.$selected->subject_name.'</option>';
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D" actually what i am storing in the session variable is subject's ID , in the next page i have to display that subjectId's subject name,